# What does the ./ (dot slash) operator represent in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to port a piece of code from Python to PHP. I've come across a line that I don't understand the notation for.

```
secLat = 1./cos(lat)
```

What does the ./ operator do in this context?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are just using a decimal followed by a divide sign to make sure the result is a float instead of an int. This avoids problems like the following:

```
>>> 1/3
0
>>> 1./3
0.3333333333333333
```

Comment: I believe because of you not explaining exactly, that it's just `(1.)/(cos(lat))`, where `1.` is just floating-point `1.0`.

Answer (score 14):

You are reading that wrong I'm afraid; it's:

```
(1.)/cos(lat)
```

so, divide floating point value `1.0` (with the zero omitted) by the `cos()` of `lat`.

Comment: This is another reason to try to follow [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations for code formatting.  An extra space and there would be no question of a `./` operator.  PEP 8 does appear to be silent on whether `1.` should be `1.0`.  What do you think is best practice?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I always use a 0 myself; there is no value in omitting it.

Answer (score 4):

It makes the 1 a float value. Equivalent to `float(1)`

With two integers, the `/` is a floor function:

```
>>> 12/5
2
```

With one argument a float, `/` acts as you expect:

```
>>> 12.0/5
2.4
>>> 12/5.0
2.4
```

IMHO, the code you posted is less ambiguous if written this way (in Python)

```
secLat = 1.0/cos(lat)
```

Or

```
secLat = float(1)/cos(lat)
```

Or

```
secLat = 1/cos(lat)
```

Since math.cos() returns a float, you can use an integer on top.

If you want Python to have a '[true division](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)' similar to Perl / PHP, you do this way:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 1/2
0.5
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you don't have to worry about it in Python either: `1/cos(lat)` will work just fine even in Python as `cos()` returns a float and you only need one float operand to force float division. Or use an up to date version of Python (3.x) to get float division by default.

Comment: @Duncan: Thanks for the comment and I changed the post to reflect.

Answer (score 2):

`1.` represents floating point number. `/` represents divide.